# Div is not appears when i am using imagejpeg to merge s

Tags: php

I am using the below code to merge and rebuild a new image, But i have an issue in it.

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo '<div style="width:640px; height:600px; margin:0 auto; margin-top:10px;">';
imagejpeg($photoFrame, $targetfile);
echo '</div>'; 
imagedestroy($photoFrame);
```

I need a div so i can put and other stuff.
When i put echo to display a div and inside of this div to display renew image jpg it doesn't work.

if I use it like this: `imagejpeg($photoFrame, $targetfile);` it works great. any ideas?

All my Code inside my php file:

```
$res = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['jsondata']), true);
/* get data */
$count_images = count($res['images']);
/* the background image is the first one */
$background     = $res['images'][0]['src'];
$photo1         = imagecreatefromjpeg($background);
$foto1W         = imagesx($photo1);
$foto1H         = imagesy($photo1);
$photoFrameW    = $res['images'][0]['width'];
$photoFrameH    = $res['images'][0]['height'];
$photoFrame     = imagecreatetruecolor($photoFrameW,$photoFrameH);
imagecopyresampled($photoFrame, $photo1, 0, 0, 0, 0, $photoFrameW, $photoFrameH, $foto1W, $foto1H);

/* the other images */
for($i = 1; $i < $count_images; ++$i){
    $insert         = $res['images'][$i]['src'];
    $photoFrame2Rotation = (180-$res['images'][$i]['rotation']) + 180;

    $photo2         = imagecreatefrompng($insert);

    $foto2W         = imagesx($photo2);
    $foto2H         = imagesy($photo2);
    $photoFrame2W   = $res['images'][$i]['width'];
    $photoFrame2H   = $res['images'][$i]['height'];

    $photoFrame2TOP = $res['images'][$i]['top'];
    $photoFrame2LEFT= $res['images'][$i]['left'];

    $photoFrame2    = imagecreatetruecolor($photoFrame2W,$photoFrame2H);
    $trans_colour   = imagecolorallocatealpha($photoFrame2, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($photoFrame2, 0, 0, $trans_colour);

    imagecopyresampled($photoFrame2, $photo2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $photoFrame2W, $photoFrame2H, $foto2W, $foto2H);

    $photoFrame2    = imagerotate($photoFrame2,$photoFrame2Rotation, -1,0);
    /*after rotating calculate the difference of new height/width with the one before*/
    $extraTop       =(imagesy($photoFrame2)-$photoFrame2H)/2;
    $extraLeft      =(imagesx($photoFrame2)-$photoFrame2W)/2;

    imagecopy($photoFrame, $photoFrame2,$photoFrame2LEFT-$extraLeft, $photoFrame2TOP-$extraTop, 0, 0, imagesx($photoFrame2), imagesy($photoFrame2));    
}
// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo '<div style="width:640px; height:600px; margin:0 auto; margin-top:10px;">';
imagejpeg($photoFrame, $targetfile);
echo '</div>'; 
imagedestroy($photoFrame);
```

Comment: Why you are sending html code with image header??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't send html code with in `image/jpg` datatype. When you set content-type to image/jpg, browser expects image data, not html with it.

Try changing like (this is in image_source.php):

```
// Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($photoFrame); // output to browser
imagedestroy($photoFrame);
```

and use it in code like:

```
echo '<div style="width:640px; height:600px; margin:0 auto; margin-top:10px;">';
echo '<img src="image_source.php" />';
echo '</div>';
```

If you want to only save the image use this (note that you have to run this just once to create image to output file):

```
$res = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['jsondata']), true);
/* get data */
$count_images = count($res['images']);
/* the background image is the first one */
$background     = $res['images'][0]['src'];
$photo1         = imagecreatefromjpeg($background);
$foto1W         = imagesx($photo1);
$foto1H         = imagesy($photo1);
$photoFrameW    = $res['images'][0]['width'];
$photoFrameH    = $res['images'][0]['height'];
$photoFrame     = imagecreatetruecolor($photoFrameW,$photoFrameH);
imagecopyresampled($photoFrame, $photo1, 0, 0, 0, 0, $photoFrameW, $photoFrameH, $foto1W, $foto1H);

/* the other images */
for($i = 1; $i < $count_images; ++$i){
    $insert         = $res['images'][$i]['src'];
    $photoFrame2Rotation = (180-$res['images'][$i]['rotation']) + 180;

    $photo2         = imagecreatefrompng($insert);

    $foto2W         = imagesx($photo2);
    $foto2H         = imagesy($photo2);
    $photoFrame2W   = $res['images'][$i]['width'];
    $photoFrame2H   = $res['images'][$i]['height'];

    $photoFrame2TOP = $res['images'][$i]['top'];
    $photoFrame2LEFT= $res['images'][$i]['left'];

    $photoFrame2    = imagecreatetruecolor($photoFrame2W,$photoFrame2H);
    $trans_colour   = imagecolorallocatealpha($photoFrame2, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($photoFrame2, 0, 0, $trans_colour);

    imagecopyresampled($photoFrame2, $photo2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $photoFrame2W, $photoFrame2H, $foto2W, $foto2H);

    $photoFrame2    = imagerotate($photoFrame2,$photoFrame2Rotation, -1,0);
    /*after rotating calculate the difference of new height/width with the one before*/
    $extraTop       =(imagesy($photoFrame2)-$photoFrame2H)/2;
    $extraLeft      =(imagesx($photoFrame2)-$photoFrame2W)/2;

    imagecopy($photoFrame, $photoFrame2,$photoFrame2LEFT-$extraLeft, $photoFrame2TOP-$extraTop, 0, 0, imagesx($photoFrame2), imagesy($photoFrame2));    
}
$targetfile = "/path/to/images/some.jpg";

// Save image to file..
imagejpeg($photoFrame, $targetfile, 80); // 80% quality
imagedestroy($photoFrame);

// Now image is created and saved to file and you can use it like any other image.
```

Comment: You mean to put your code bellow: header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($photoFrame); // output to browser
imagedestroy($photoFrame); ?>  ?

Comment: No, image processing file only outputs image data. Those are two different files. checkout the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Comment: Correct... I use imagejpeg($photoFrame, 'uploads/image.jpg'); and saved the image and then i used session to store the path/filename. So far so good. Now how can i prevent to do not show the image? Coz and with this imagejpeg($photoFrame, 'uploads/image.jpg'); it stills to show the image.. i want to save it only

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how. Remove all output and header stuff.